# Connection not closed even if call is verified

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, junit, mockito

Can you help me understand this piece of code?

I am trying to verify that database connection is closed.
Even if Mocikto verifies that close() method were called connection is not closed.

Code I am testing (it uses inside con.close()):

```
public static void closeConnection(CallableStatement cs, Connection conn) {
    JdbcUtils.closeStatement(cs);
    JdbcUtils.closeConnection(conn);
}
```

And test:

```
public class DataProviderTest {

    @InjectMocks
    DataProvider dataProvider;

    @Mock
    OracleConnection oracleConnection;

    @Mock
    DatabaseMetaData databaseMetadata;

    @Mock
    PoolDataSource dataSource;

    @Mock
    OracleCallableStatement oracleCallableStatement;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() throws SQLException {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(dataProvider, "parseSQLErrorFuntion", "Some SQL error function");
        Mockito.when(dataSource.getConnection()).thenReturn(oracleConnection);
        Mockito.when(oracleConnection.getMetaData()).thenReturn(databaseMetadata);
        Mockito.when(oracleConnection.prepareCall(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(oracleCallableStatement);
    }

    @Test
    public void closeConnectionTest() throws SQLException {
        OracleConnection connection = dataProvider.getConnection();
        OracleCallableStatement statement = oracleCallableStatement;
        assertFalse(connection.isClosed());
        dataProvider.closeConnection(statement, connection);
        Mockito.verify(connection, Mockito.atLeast(1)).close(); //pass
        Mockito.verify(statement, Mockito.atLeast(1)).close();  //pass

        assertTrue(connection.isClosed()); // expected: <true> but was: <false>

    }

}
```

Comment: You might want to consider switching to try-with-resources instead of using methods like your `closeConnection` and `JdbcUtils.closeStatement/closeConnection`; those are crutches that were largely made obsolete and unnecessary with the introduction of try-with-resources in Java 7.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I would if I could :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connection in your test is a mocked object, therefor running the close method does not actually change the value of isClosed from false to true.
You can remove the last assert, since it's a mock, all you need to verify is that the close method was executed on the connection, you don't need to verify what it did.